# Contravariant Hom and colimits

Tags: number-theory, homological-algebra

I want to show that $$\hom(\lim_{\leftarrow} \mu_d,\overline{\mathbb{F}_\ell}^\times) \simeq \lim_{\rightarrow} \hom(\mu_d , \overline{\mathbb{F}_\ell}^\times)$$ where $\ell$ is prime, $\mu_d$ is the cyclic group with order $d$ and $d$ is coprime to $\ell$.

According to Proposition 5.26 of  "An introduction to homological algebra", Rotman, contravariant $\hom$ transforms limits into colimits, but it seems untrue if we want to transform colimits into limits.

However, in this case, maybe it can be used Hibert's theorem 90, but I don't know how it can help.

Comment: Actually, contravariant hom always transforms colimits into limits. In _very_ special circumstances it also transforms certain limits into colimits. In your situation you seem to be dealing with pro-groups.

Comment: Do you have some reference of this?

Comment: Which one? That contravariant hom transforms colimits into limits is almost by definition. You will probably find it as an exercise in any category theory textbook. The claim about profinite groups I am not so familiar with but it is due to Stone duality.